# Display selected content at top of page using Angular 2+

Tags: angular7

I have designed a Dashboard. This dashboard, I used `mat-expansion-panel`. When  expanded the content are showing below as expected.

what I want to achieve is

- When I click on the panel should come in focus and when we expand expansion panel it should display at the top of the page.
- Also when we click on any div as if it is scrolled below that content should come on top of the page.

Please suggest how to achieve the following.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, Please try to explain what you are trying to do and what approaches you have tried till now ? etc.

Comment: I have designed a Dashboard in that I have used mat-expansion-panel after expanding that the content are showing below. what I want is... when I click on that the panel should come in focus

Comment: I have edited question as mentioned in the comments.